# (MongoDB) aggregate project failing to return value

Tags: mongodb

I have successfully completed a $lookup and now I would like to define what fields should be listed using $project.
My collection is a bit weird as it has another grouping before showing the array, so compname.name for example isn't returning anything. How do I perform a project with this additional grouping "0" in the way?

This is my first $project that works

```
  /**
     * specifications: The fields to
     *   include or exclude.
     */
    {
      compname: 1
    }
```

This is the output of the above $project

```
 /* output */
       id: ObjectId("5fa571d148065e4ec8f77c12")
        compname:Array
         0:Object
          _id: ObjectId("5f5237efa70fd23677238428")
          members:Array
          units:Array
          deals:Array
          templates:Array
          name:"Company 1"
          hierarchy:Array
          __v:705
          links:Array
          clauses:Array
          sections:Array
          certification:"PLATINUM"
          pendingMembers:Array
          address:Object
          website:
          lastMemberLeft:2021-08-04T09:27:25.917+00:00
          created:2021-08-02T10:35:35.003+00:00
          straightToLease:Object
```

I am trying to call "name" from the above output only so I try but it returns blank

```
/**
     * specifications: The fields to
     *   include or exclude.
     */
    {
      compname.name: 1
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266 Provide sample input and desired output data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pipeline with lookup and so you can use $project for your relation in the pipeline.

Edit 'from', 'let' and 'pipeline.$match.$expr' by yourself.

Notice: 'indicator_id' is a variable.

```js
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'companies',
    let: { indicator_id: '$_id' },
    as: 'compname',
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$indicator_id'] },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450445/mongodb-compass-lookup-using-let-not-working if you can thanks.