# (MongoDB Compass) lookup using let not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Not sure whats wrong with my code any help?

units collection

```
_id: ObjectId("5fa571d148065e4ec8f77c12")
 actors:Array
 deals:Array
 name:"6th Floor"
 area:2500
 condition:"CATEGORY_A"
 organisation:ObjectId("5f7de0fbd0d5403fee33fb10")
```

organisation collection

```
_id: ObjectId("5f7de0fbd0d5403fee33fb10")
 members:Array
 units:Array
 deals:Array
 templates:Array
 name:"ChApps Ltd"
```

Output

```
      {from: 'organisations',
      let: {_id: '$organisation'}
      pipeline: [{$match:{$expr:{$eq:['$_id','$$_id']}}}],
      as: 'compname'}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is missing comma `,` after `let: {_id: '$organisation'}` statement.